# Javascript error when using bundles

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have the following bundles.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/description").Include(
             "~/Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/form-validation.js",
            "~/Scripts/fancybox.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/elements.js",
            "~/Scripts/descriptionPage.js"
        ));
```

on my LayoutPage I have the following which renders the relevant scripts

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

now inside my View which is located in an area I then register the description bundle as so

```
@section scripts{
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/description")
}
```

now when I view source I see the following

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/form-validation.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/elements.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/descriptionPage.js"></script>
```

Everything is there as expected, problem is jquery-2.1.3.min.js is colored red when viewing source and the error I get when using firebug is and when mousing over the script tag whilst viewing source is stray start tag 'script'

[image]

So I decided to start commenting out js files to find the file and it turns out its dropzone.min.js commenting this out the error goes away, can anyone tell me or help me figure this out?

Comment: cannot see the image

Comment: @OliSoproniB. I can see, hmmmm it says TypeError: a is null and points to jquery min file

Comment: sorry its being block by our network.. check it later after work